# Align child element to bottom with CSS

Tags: css, xhtml

I have a form `input`, and the `label` spans multiple lines, and I want the corresponding checkbox to appear at the bottom (last line of the `label` element).

Here is what I was playing with

### CSS

```
.standard-form {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }


.standard-form .input-row {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 0.8em;
}

.standard-form label {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.standard-form .input-container {
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
}

  .standard-form .checkbox .input-container {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;

}
```

### HTML

```
<form class="standard-form">
<div class="input-row checkbox" id="permission">
                        <label for="input-permission">
               Do I hereby grant you permission to do whatever tasks are neccessary to achieve an ideal outcome?            </label>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="checkbox" id="input-permission" name="permission" value="true" />            </div>

        </div>
  </form>
```

It is also online at [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/ocovu/edit).

Is there any way to do this? I notice that `div.input-container` isn't expanding, which is the old multi column problem with CSS.

I thought I could get this going with `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: bottom` but I haven't been able to do it yet. I don't mind that IE6/7 won't render it correctly.

I have also tried using a combination of `position: relative;` with the child `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` except then I need to specify a height which I can not guarantee will be the height of the label on the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my changes in action: http://jsbin.com/ocovu/2/edit

Here are the relevant declarations:

```
.standard-form .input-row {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 0.8em;
  position: relative;
}
.standard-form .checkbox .input-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:-2px;
  left:25%;
}
```

Comment: Would it work if instead you used a relatively positioned element with a negative top margin? ... it don't know why but I 've always been scared of position: absolute

Comment: @CurtainDog there's no reason to fear position: absolute when used properly. I don't see why negative margin wouldn't work in this circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

Tried `display: block`?